# set -x and wildcard expansion

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

In shell scripts, our corporate coding standard requires using...

```
set -x
command
set +x
```

...for logging, rather than...

```
echo "doing command"
command
```

However, when a wildcard is part of the command, this can produce very verbose output.

For example...

```
for i in {1..10}; do touch $i.foo; done; # create 10 foo files
set -x   # log command execution (stdout to be redirected to log file)
rm *.foo # delete foo files
set +x   # end logging
```

...produces the output...

```
rm 10.foo 1.foo 2.foo 3.foo 4.foo 5.foo 6.foo 7.foo 8.foo 9.foo
```

Okay for 10 files, but not so great for 10,000.

The desired output is...

```
rm *.foo
```

My first thought was to put *.foo in quotes...

```
rm "*.foo"
```

However, that gives the error...

```
rm: cannot remove ‘*.foo’: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way, using set -x, to echo the command without expanding the wildcard?

Comment: No; `set -x` is a debugging tool, not a logging tool. I would ask whoever enforces the policy what they would like to see as a workaround.

Comment: Mind you, this *is* a much better practice than `echo rm *.foo` is (as `echo` throws away information about where argument boundaries sit).

Comment: BTW, passing 10,000 files on a single `rm` command line isn't guaranteed to work at all (as it's liable to go over the operating system's command line length limit). There's a point when you'd want to, say, `find . -name '*.foo' -delete` just for performance reasons -- so maybe the `set -x` output becoming unreasonable should be taken as a signal that code should be fixed, instead of read as something to work around. :)

Comment: (Mind you, `set -v` might be considered as an alternative that doesn't run expansions; however, for that very reason, it's unsuitable for a lot of the purposes that `set -x` serves, so I wouldn't do that cutover without getting the blessing of the folks who wrote the policy in question; sometimes, one can't track down a bug from the logs without seeing *exactly* what strings `*.foo` expanded to; f/e, if you had a file named `-.foo` in your current directory, it would break your code unless you changed it to `rm -- *.foo`, because it would be trying to set `-.`, `-f` and `-o` flags).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The example above is very simplified, but one thing I like about `echo ...` is that it gives me full control over the exact parameters that are output. I can use any combination of literal text, variables, or even backticked command output. `set -whatever` is much more limited.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener, there's no possible way to know the difference between `echo somecommand "argument 1" "argument 2"` and `echo somecommand "argument" "1" "argument" "2"`, even though they're utterly unlike each other, because `echo` throws away information. If you want control, implement your own log function: `log_and_run() { printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'; "$@"; }`, then `log_and_run ls *.txt`.

Comment: If you want a more in-depth description of why `echo` is awful and should never be used with dynamic or unknown arguments by anyone, see the excellent answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113 -- or for a shorter read, see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the POSIX specification for `echo` at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html; *the `echo` specification itself* advises using `printf` instead!

Answer (score 1):

For many cases, where simple '-x' or '-v' do not work (as per comments above), and staying within your coding standard (no separate echo), consider:

```
VAR=/tmp/123
$SHELL -cv "ls $VAR/*"
```

which will execute the command, but will log the command WITH variable substitution, command substitution, but WITHOUT wild-card substitution.